# Nearby Messages API does not work for applications with different bundleId

Tags: ios, google-nearby-messages

Does anyone know what has changed in the Nearby Messages API service recently and could explain the described problem? (Only iOS applications with same `bundleId` can communicate with each other.)

I created two iOS applications with different `bundleId`s. These applications communicate with each other using the [Nearby Messages API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/ios/pub-sub).

The applications worked properly - until about 2 weeks ago, the Nearby Messages service stopped working.

I suspect the Nearby Messages API changed because nothing was changed in the application code.

The following are logs from the NearbyMessages-1.1.1 library:

```
2020-12-23 15:34:38.330220+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: Success
2020-12-23 15:34:38.330582+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 3 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 unpublish results(s), 0 subscription results(s), 0 unsubscribe results(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:38.334692+0100 Client[375:11734] Tokens: 3 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2020-12-23 15:34:38.334985+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC request: 3 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 3 directive(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:38.943624+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: Success
2020-12-23 15:34:38.943897+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 3 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 unpublish results(s), 0 subscription results(s), 0 unsubscribe results(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:43.831088+0100 Client[375:11734] Tokens: 3 good, 0 bad, 0 broadcast
2020-12-23 15:34:43.831899+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC request: 3 token(s), 0 beacon(s), 3 directive(s)
2020-12-23 15:34:44.472385+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: Success
2020-12-23 15:34:44.472755+0100 Client[375:11734] Report RPC response: 0 directive(s), 3 token(s), 0 message(s), 0 publication results(s), 0 unpublish results(s), 0 subscription results(s), 0 unsubscribe results(s)
```

As you can see the library notices the presence of a second phone, however, the `MessageFoundHandler` is not notified.

Only when I set the same `bundleId` for both applications, the Nearby service starts to work again.

It appears Nearby Messages API has started to restrict message visibility only to recipients using the same `bundleId`- at least that is what I am seeing.

Based on the documentation of the service:

```
5. The server facilitates message exchange between two devices when both are associated with a common token, and the API keys used by the calling apps are associated with the same project in the Google Developers Console.
```

Despite the above condition being met, the service does not work as it should when we have communication between different applications.

If it helps: I performed the tests using an iPhone 6s and an iPhone 11

Comment: Today the service has started working properly again. Does anyone know the causes of the described problem? 
I cannot afford to suspend the production application for several weeks.

Comment: related with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176461658